# Is there any free password manager that supports fingerprint reader?

Tags: windows, security, password-manager

I'm looking for a free password manager that supports unlocking/authentication via built-in fingerprint reader (either through Windows Hello or some custom solution).

I've already found that [premium version of Lastpass is able to support it](https://www.howtogeek.com/284240/how-to-log-in-to-your-lastpass-password-vault-with-your-fingerprint-in-windows/). I wonder if there are any Keepass plugins or any other less known managers that can do that.

If not - could you please tell me what's the reason for such state? Biometric security seems like great way to protect your password database.

Comment: Enpass may be worth a look.